# Fast way to check if $f(x)>x$ for what value of $x$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, list-manipulation, parallelization, inequalities

In order to find the value $x$ for which $f(x)>x$, I tried it using the following code:

```
ParallelTable[If[TrueQ[f[x]>x],x,Nothing],{x,0,10^9}]
```

For some function $f(x)$. But it takes forever, is there a way to make it go faster?

Comment: Have you tested your code with a simple function f and a smaller range?

Comment: @mikado yes I did.

Comment: Do you expect your function only to satisfy the condition for one value of x?

Comment: @mikado No I expect it to have infinitely many.

Comment: Would `NSolve[f[x]==x,x]` help find a boundary of the region?

Comment: @mikado No it does not, unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain your problem further

Comment: What about something like `FindInstance[f[x] > x && 0 <= x <= 10^9, x, Reals]` ?

Comment: @flinty Than I get the following: `The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.`

Comment: What is `f[x]` please?

Comment: @flinty $\cot(x)$ for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It work or not?

```
Reduce[Cos[x] > x && -6 < x < 6, x, Reals] // N
Reduce[N[{Cos[x] > x && -6 < x < 6}], x, Reals]
```

plot

[image]

```
  Clear["`*"];
fig = Plot[{Cos[x], 0}, {x, -6, 6}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[x, Cos[x] - x]}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Directive[Opacity[0.1], Blue], Red}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @flinty hints in a comment, it can depend on the function.  For [`Cot[x]` (from OP's commment)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228988/fast-way-to-check-if-fxx-for-what-value-of-x/228994#comment581113_228988), which is vectorized (& auto-parallelized) in the MKL, here is a way:

```
Block[{chunk = 10^9/20000},
  Table[
    Round@Pick[#, UnitStep[# - Cot@#], 0] &@
     Range[chunk*k + 1., chunk*(k + 1)],
    {k, 0, 10^9/chunk - 1}
    ] // Flatten
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> (*
>   {9.04107, {22, 44, 355, 710, 1065, 1420, 1775, 2130, 2485, 2840, 3195,
>      312689, 1146408, 5419351, 10838702}}
> *)
> ```

Note 1: A **key** for the function `Cot[x]` is to avoid `Cot[0]`, which is `ComplexInfinity`. Avoiding non-`Real` results allows the computation to use efficient packed arrays.

Note 2: How to chunk the computations depends on the system.  The full `10^9` causes my memory to thrash. With `chunk = 10^9/10`, the timing comes down to 18-19 sec.  Then it decreases until around `10^9/20000`.